# Why won't the join tool cut through these edges?

Tags: modeling, edges

I've been trying to find a way to add faces to the top of this mesh so that there are no double edges. Every attempt I have tried has failed. The Grid fill creates a maze of criss crossed lines. Bridge edge loops creates crossed faces. The knife tool refuses to cut through the top of the mesh and cuts down the side, (and I cannot make head nor tail of the constraints options for the knife tool at the bottom of the prompt bar).
So I thought just joining 2 vertices would cut through any existing edges. It doesn't, it refuses to cut through. Only the Face tool 'F' works and of course, creates edges crossing over edges with no additional vertices.
So how do I properly add faces to the top of this mesh so it is divided up with squares in each corner, a square in the middle and rectangles filling in the gaps, with no crossed over edges? I'm lost.
[image]

Comment: Fill the faces and use the knife tool to create a clean topology?

Comment: Damnit! I hate it when it's something so bloody obvious. Thanks once again moonbot. This is the quickets question answer response I've ever received.
How do I turn your comment into the answer?

Comment: @smashingtuck if you like you can just post his comment as the answer and attribute it to moonboots :)

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie what's the point of posting a single-sentence answer now that Gordon posted a full answer? It's basically the same, except Gordon replaced knife with the join operator (in this case, straight lines, so no difference)

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady yes i agree but maybe the solution of moonboots is what worked for him?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might be a dumb question, but is there a reason you keep these two edges?

[image: manifold edges]

Because I cannot see a reason to keep them if you want to close the top, just select them and hit <kbd>X</kbd> > *Delete* > *Edges*:

[image: delete edges]

Then select the top edge loop by holding <kbd>Alt</kbd> and clicking on one of the top edges:

[image: select top edge loop]

Now just hit <kbd>F</kbd> and the top is completely filled with an n-gon. Afterwards you can select whatever vertices you want and join them with <kbd>J</kbd> to split the n-gon into multiple faces.

[image: fill top]